# IP address question

Tags: email, ip

I traced a header on an email I received, the person claims to have sent it from Maryland, but I traced the IP and it shows shows San Jose, CA and also contains loop backs, ??? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Maybe the sender uses VPN or proxy, or the IP he uses belongs to a entity hosted in San Jose but have a remote link to Maryland, or he is using remote access software from Maryland to San Jose.

And about the loopbacks, it's very common. Mail servers often work in clusters, so it's possible that one mail server received the email, and forwarded to another mail in the same network, or to another process in the same server.

Comment: True, and the person sending it may not be aware of it, or even that someone would find a problem with that.